# ERROR at line 3: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running the below `SELECT` statement to:

1. Return prices from a standard price list `customer = 0`
2. If the customer has been quoted a special price `customer = X` then use that price instead

I am getting the error message:

```
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Oracle version is: Oracle8i Enterprise Edition Release 8.1.7.4.0 - Production.

```
SELECT     glas_daten_basis.idnr, glas_daten_basis.gl_bez, NVL(p2.zum2, p1.zum2)
FROM       glas_daten_basis
JOIN       os_przu p1 ON p1.idnr = glas_daten_basis.idnr
LEFT JOIN  os_przu p2 ON p2.idnr = glas_daten_basis.idnr AND p2.kunr = 63
WHERE      p1.kunr = 0;
```

Line 3 is the `JOIN`, is there something wrong here?

**Update:** There are 137 rows in the standard price list, so I should be given 137 rows regardless of whether the price is from `customer = 0` or `customer = X`. The answers so far give me a ~60 rows for some reason.

```
SELECT     os_przu.idnr, os_przu.zum2
FROM       os_przu
WHERE      os_przu.kunr = 0;
...
137 rows selected.
```

Comment: Oracle 8 does not support explicit `JOIN`s. You need to upgrade to an Oracle version from this century

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there a workaround? This is the embedded database version that our application is sold with. I have no control over it.

Comment: INNER JOIN, LEFT Join, Right Join, FUll Outer JOin, natural join, cross join... (the line after from that starts join needs to define the join type. http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj29840.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @a_horse-with_no_name said, ANSI joins don't work in 8i; they weren't added until 9i. So if you're really stuck on this ancient and unsupported version you're stuck with the old Oracle-specific syntax:

```
SELECT     glas_daten_basis.idnr, glas_daten_basis.gl_bez, NVL(p2.zum2, p1.zum2)
FROM       glas_daten_basis, os_przu p1, os_przu p2 
WHERE      p1.idnr = glas_daten_basis.idnr
AND        p1.kunr = 0
AND        p2.idnr (+) = glas_daten_basis.idnr
AND        p2.kunr (+) = 63;
```

Which is pretty similar to @nelucon's answer, except that only had one `(+)` left-join marker and it was on the wrong side of the condition.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb453/1).

The `(+)` is the [Oracle-specific outer-join operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries006.htm#SQLRF52354), and it has to be applied to each condition for the outer-joined table - if one is missed then the rest are ignored and it effectively becomes an inner join again. (One of the reasons ANSI joins are easier to work with, though you can still get that wrong by referring to the joined table in the `where` clause as well as the `on`.)

Answer (score 0):

something like this, i didn't test the code but you got it. (+) means the left join. for more infos, google for "oracle 8 left join"

```
SELECT     glas_daten_basis.idnr, glas_daten_basis.gl_bez, NVL(p2.zum2, p1.zum2)
FROM       glas_daten_basis, os_przu p1, os_przu p2 
WHERE      p1.kunr = 0
AND        p1.idnr = glas_daten_basis.idnr
AND        p2.idnr = glas_daten_basis.idnr (+)
AND        p2.kunr = 6;
```

Comment: The final `p2.numr = 6` is effectively converting it back to an inner join. That needs to be `p2.kunr = 63 (+)`.

Comment: @AlexPoole The original answer doesn't return the correct number of rows anyhow (check the update in the question), but when I add the last `(+)` that you suggested I get the error message `ERROR at line 6: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`.

Comment: @user3805423 - sorry, copied the answer's positioning; the left joins should be on the other side.